# DKMS driver stuck, can't uninstall

Tags: drivers, kernel, dkms

I seem to not be able to remove a DKMS driver for Digimend.

```
sudo dkms remove digimend/9 --all

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 9
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
```

All seems fine but when I remove/install a package I get

```
Setting up digimend-dkms (9) ...
Loading new digimend-9 DKMS files...
Building for 5.4.0-37-generic
Building initial module for 5.4.0-37-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/digimend-dkms.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.4.0-37-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/digimend/9/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package digimend-dkms (--configure):
 installed digimend-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.64ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.24-1ubuntu3) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 digimend-dkms
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

**Make.log**

```
DKMS make.log for digimend-9 for kernel 5.4.0-37-generic (x86_64)
jue 11 jun 2020 08:28:50 AST
make -C /lib/modules/5.4.0-37-generic/build SUBDIRS=/var/lib/dkms/digimend/9/build modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-37-generic'
  DESCEND  objtool
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-37-generic/tools/build/Makefile.build:37: /usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-37-generic/tools/build/Build.include: No such file or directory
make[5]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-37-generic/tools/build/Build.include'.  Stop.
make[4]: *** [Makefile:43: /usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-37-generic/tools/objtool/fixdep-in.o] Error 2
make[3]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-37-generic/tools/build/Makefile.include:5: fixdep] Error 2
make[2]: *** [Makefile:67: objtool] Error 2
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1823: tools/objtool] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-37-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:22: modules] Error 2
```

Comment: Try "sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq digimend-dkms " .

Comment: @ParsaMousavi that worked, post as answer please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force removal of any package using `dpkg` with the option `--force-remove-reinstreq` :

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq digimend-dkms
```